# How to create project on MVC5, since it is now ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework)?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Actually I have bought Wrox 's book MVC5 . I don't have knowledge in MVC. Since ASP.NET5 is now ASP.NET Core (.NET framework) & ASP.NET 6 is now ASP.NET Core (.NET Core).

How to get start with the book? Can I follow the book for ASP.NET Core (.NET framework)  (which is renamed from ASP.NET5)?

(I have knowledge in ASP.NET Webform, I made some project on it)

Comment: MVC is just a design pattern. You'll be just fine following this book.

Comment: But it totally different from Webform.. :( and probably ASP.NET core MVC much different from ASP.NET 5 MVC

Comment: ASP.NET Core is the new name for ASP.NET 5, they are the same.

Comment: Better to check the given solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as follows:

---

***New***

ASP.NET 5 --> ASP.NET Core --> Can target multiple frameworks, like:

- Full .NET framework (not cross platform)
- Core framework (cross platform)

MVC 6 --> MVC Core

- Add as nugetpackage/middleware to your ASP.NET Core project

***Old***

ASP.NET 4.6

- Targets full .NET framework (not cross platform)

MVC 5

- Added as reference to the project

---

So, it is not a simple rename. There is no ASP.NET 6. ASP.NET Core is build from scratch and is incompatible with anything ASP.NET 4.6 related. So in other words, you can't follow Wrox's book about MVC 5 to make ASP.NET Core projects. However when you're done with the book the MVC stuff in Core projects will look familair because the API is similar.

Comment: Sorry sir, I don't get that. :(

Comment: Reformatted my answer. Is it better understandable? Or perhaps you can pinpoint what you don't get.

Answer (score 0):

MVC is a design pattern and it stand for **"Model View Controller"**. In that book you can learn the basics idea about MVC5.

ASP.NET Core (previously known as ASP.NET 5) is a Open-Source. I think it was renamed in January 2016 and It's a Cross platform support ( Build & Run on windows, Linux and Mac ).

Before creating a project in Asp.Net Core. You should integrate the .Net Core features in VisualStudio 2015.

**Step 1 :**

First download Visual Studio 2015 with Update 3 through the link [click here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowsvs2015).

**Step 2 :**

Go to Install .NET Core tools preview for Visual Studio. This .NET Core tools adds support for .NET Core projects in Visual Studio 2015.